# Using fqdn_rand and remove numbers from a pool

Tags: puppet

Is there anyway I can ensure that the pool of numbers used when calling fqdn_rand will never pick the same number in a single puppet run?

I have a cronjob and I never want any of my 5 jobs to run on the same day. I've been using fqdn_rand to generate the jobs on random days but finding some servers will have jobs which run on the same days. In my mind if these numbers are removed from the possible selected numbers, I'll never get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anyway I can ensure that the pool of numbers used when calling fqdn_rand will never pick the same number in a single puppet run?

You cannot ensure that multiple calls to `fqdn_rand()` will all return distinct values.  However, you *can* use `fqdn_rand()` to perform a selection of multiple items without duplication.  There are several ways you could do that, but I'm going to suggest combining it with the [`reduce()`](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/function.html#reduce) function to perform a (partial) shuffle of the list of options from which you want to select.

It isn't clear in the question whether you want to select from days of the week, days of the month, or something else, but for simplicity, I'll assume that you are selecting among days of the week, in the form of numbers 1 through 7:

```
  $day_numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]
```

Although Puppet does not have general purpose looping statements such as `for` or `while`, you can iterate (among other ways) by using one of several [iteration functions](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/lang_iteration.html#lang_iteration-iteration-functions) to process an iterable value.  For example:

```
  $selected = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ].reduce($day_numbers) |$numbers, $i| {
    $selection = fqdn_rand($day_numbers.length - $i - 1, $i)
    [ 
      $numbers[0, $i],                # The already selected numbers
      $numbers[$selection + $i, -1],  # The tail starting at the next selection
      $numbers[$i, $selection]        # The slice between the previous two
    ].flatten
  }[0, 5]
```

That executes the lambda five times, associating successive values from 0 to 4 with variable `$i`.  On the initial iteration, `$day_numbers` is associated with `$numbers`.  On each subsequent iteration, the return value of the lambda's previous iteration is associated with `$numbers`.

On each iteration of the lambda, the `$i` elements selected in previous iterations occupy the first `$i` positions of `$numbers`.  The `fqdn_rand()` function is used to compute the index of one of the other elements, then the tail is rotated to bring the selected element into position.

Ultimately, an array containing the first five elements of the result (those being all the selected values) is assigned to `$selected`.

Comment: Very clever, thank you for your efforts :D

Comment: Suppose the array is words ([‘Monday’, ‘Tuesday’…]) and I need a selection of one word/day per iteration of a separate each loop ( with String name, Hash function), any ideas how I’d go about doing that? I can follow this when it works on the principals of numbers with an index but get a bit lost when it comes to implementation. I feel like I need to use map somewhere. I’ll ask a new question if It justifies one, I probably wasn’t clear in this question and was optimistic when I got a response.

Comment: @keeer, if you like, you can totally create a map (`{ 0 => 'Monday', 1 => 'Tuesday' ... }`), select numbers, and then use the map to convert numbers to names.  Alternativively, you could use an array of the day names, and take the selected numbers as indexes into that array.  But ultimately, the approach presented above does not actually depend on the members of `$day_numbers` to be numbers.  They could as easily be day names instead.